# Open MySQL from the terminal

Tags: mysql, command-line, terminal

I have installed MySQL on my macbook and would like to access MySQL through the terminal by simply typing mysql. How do I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add MySQL to the $PATH so when you type in mysql into the terminal, it will load.

To do this you need to open the terminal and type the following:

```
sudo nano /etc/profile
```

You'll then be asked for your computer password (not your MySQL password). GNU Nano will then open. Type the following:

```
export PATH=/usr/local/mysql/bin:$PATH
```

Press CTRL O, Enter then CTRL X.

Type into terminal:

```
source /etc/profile
```

You're now ready to start using MySQL from the terminal. Make sure the MySQL Server is running (easiest way is to open system preferences -> MySQL -> start MySQL Server).

In the terminal, to open MySQL, type the following (you'll be asked for the password for your connection):

```
mysql -u root -p
```

You can change root to whatever the MySQL connection username is. To make sure you're connected to the right connection, type:
show

```
show databases;
```

This will show you the databases available on the MySQL connection you've opened.

Answer (score 0):

```
echo 'export PATH=/usr/local/mysql/bin:$PATH' >> ~/.bash_profile

. ~/.bash_profile

mysql -u root -p
```

Comment: It would be great if you could explain line by line